# C program to calculate user input in a string and print out a total cost into an int

Tags: c

Can anyone help me understand this question and help with the answer, I have been trying to figure it out all day.

Mark Daniels is a carpenter who creates personalized house signs. He wants an application to compute the price of any sign a customer orders, based on the following factors:
 * The minimum charge for all signs is $30.
 * If the sign is made of oak, add $15. No charge is added for pine.
 * The first six letters or numbers are included in the minimum charge; there is a $3 charge for each additional character.
 * Black or white characters are included in the minimum charge; there is an additional $12 charge for gold-leaf lettering.
 Ask the user for the following:
 1) Whether their sign is Oak (O) or Pine (P)
 2) How many letters or character their sign is
 3) What type of lettering do they want Gold (G) or Normal(N)
  Then print out the cost of their sign

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdint.h>>

    int main()
    {
        const int MIN_CHARGE = 30;
        const int OAK_CHARGE = 15;
        const int PINE_CHARGE = 0;
        char woodType;
        int lettercount;
        const int ADDITION_CHAR;
        char textType;
        const int GOLD_LEAF = 12;
        int totalCost;



        printf("Type 'O' for Oak and 'P' for Pine: ");
        scanf_s("%c",&woodType, 1);
            if (woodType = 'O')
            {
                totalCost = MIN_CHARGE + OAK_CHARGE;
                printf("The total cost of oak is: %d", &wood);
            }
            else
        {
            totalCost = MIN_CHARGE;
            printf("The total cost of pine is: %d\n", totalCost);
        }

        printf("How many letters or numbers are in your sign? ");
        scanf_s("%d", &lettercount);

            if (lettercount > 6)
            {
                totalCost = totalCost + ADDITION_CHAR * (lettercount - 6);
                printf("The total cost of letters is: %d", totalCost);
            }

        else
        {
            printf("Type 'G' for Gold and 'N' for normal letters \n");
            scanf_s("%c", &textType, 1);

        }
            if (textType == 'G' || textType == 'g')
            {
                totalCost = totalCost + GOLD_LEAF;
                printf("The total cost of gold leaf letters is: %d\n", totalCost);
            }


        printf("The total cost of sign is: %d\n", totalCost);

        return 0;
    }`
```

Comment: I keep receiving these errors
Warning C4477 'printf' : format string '%d' requires an argument of type 'int', but variadic argument 1 has type 'int *'      
Warning C4700 uninitialized local variable 'ADDITION_CHAR'

Comment: 'printf("The total cost of oak is: %d", &wood);'.... what is '&wood' ?

Comment: Fix those errors first. The ADDITION_CHAR one, for example, has a clear reason: *it has no value*.

Comment: ADDITION_CHAR is supposed to be when lettercount is greater than six for each number it is add 3, how do you assign that value?

Comment: I was trying to see if should combine OAK and PINE CHARGE into one variable.

Answer (score 1):

Richard. I hope you are doing great!

1. The question doesn´t say to inform the total cost after entering the values. If I were you, I wouldn't do it. Just keep things easy and do only what the question wants.

   `printf("The total cost of oak is: %d", &wood);` On this line, you forgot to declare de variable 'wood'
2. Here, your code is totally wrong.

   `if (lettercount > 6)
           {
               totalCost = totalCost + ADDITION_CHAR * (lettercount - 6);
               printf("The total cost of letters is: %d", totalCost);
           } else {
           printf("Type 'G' for Gold and 'N' for normal letters \n");
           scanf_s(" %c", &textType, 1);
           }`

   What you are doing wrong here has to do with the 'else'. Here, if he needs more than 6 letters the program won't let the user say if he wants gold or normal letters.
3. Finally, here you have to put a space before '%c'. This may seem weird, but to know why you have to use a space before '%c' you will need to know about what is a buffer. You can learn more about them [here](https://www.sitesbay.com/cprogramming/c-buffer-concept).

   `printf("Type 'G' for Gold and 'N' for normal letters \n");
           scanf_s("%c", &textType, 1);`

Overall, your code needs more attention. Things like trying to use less variable can help you a lot, especially in microcontrollers (I don't know if that's your goal). Also, you can check my own resolution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>>

int main(){
        const int OAK_CHARGE   = 15;
        const int GOLD_LEAF    = 12;
        const int ADDITION_CHAR = 3;
        char woodType, textType;
        int lettercount = 0;
        int totalCost = 30;

        printf("Type 'O' for Oak or 'P' for Pine: ");
        scanf_s(" %c",&woodType, 1);
        if (woodType == 'O' || woodType == 'o'){
            totalCost += OAK_CHARGE;
        }

        printf("How many letters or numbers are in your sign? ");
        scanf_s("%d", &lettercount);
        if (lettercount > 6){
            totalCost += ADDITION_CHAR*(lettercount - 6);
        }

        printf("Type 'G' for Gold and 'N' for normal letters: ");
        scanf_s(" %c",&textType, 1);
        if (textType == 'G' || textType == 'g'){
            totalCost += GOLD_LEAF;
        }

        printf("The total cost of sign is: %d", totalCost);
        return 0;
    }
```

Please note that may exist better solutions. Everyone has their style of coding.
Well, I hope I've been useful!